# How to create a grid of images using flexbox that fully wraps around a main image?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create a grid of images that first has a large featured image, then to it's right, has a grid of 4 (2 on each row).. and then underneath that, rows of 4 images at a time.

Loosely based on [this design](http://news.microsoft.com/stories/).

I think flexbox would probably be able to nail this one.

Say I have some markup like this

```
 <div class="image-grid">
   <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1024/1024">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1000/800">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1100/1000">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1120/1000">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1130/1024">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1101/1024">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1020/1024">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1021/1024">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1002/1024">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1003/1024">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1004/1024">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1005/1024">
  </div>
</div>
```

with CSS

```
.image-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.image-grid > div:first-child {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.image-grid > div {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}
```

this *almost* does what I need it to. Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/magician11/pen/ZWRbVv?editors=0100).

I need two things fixed though...

1. display 4 images to the right of the featured image, instead of the current 2.
2. stretch each image to fit it's space so it's a tight grid (no spacing around any image). I'm thinking of using the `object-fit` CSS property but I haven't got it working yet.

Thank you.

Comment: code updated ! anyways your question was like wrap all images around one featured image and i did the same in last code , now code updated as per your recent  comment

Answer (score 0):

```css
.image-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.image-grid, .featured > img:first-child {
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
}
.image-grid > img {
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-grid featured">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1024/1024">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1000/800">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1100/1000">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1120/1000">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1130/1024">
</div>
<div class="image-grid">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1101/1024">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1020/1024">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1021/1024">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1002/1024">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1003/1024">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1004/1024">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1005/1024">
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but I only want 4 images to the right of the main image. Not every image.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured the easiest way would be to use a framework like Foundation to create the top row, and then use flexbox for the rest.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-6 columns featured-image">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1023/1024">
  </div>
  <div class="medium-6 columns featured-image-grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="medium-6 columns">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1024/1024">
      </div>
      <div class="medium-6 columns">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1022/1024">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="medium-6 columns">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1021/1024">
      </div>
      <div class="medium-6 columns">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1020/1024">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="image-grid">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1020/1024">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1020/1025">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1020/1022">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1020/1021">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1020/1029">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1020/1028">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1020/1027">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1020/1023">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1020/1024">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1020/1025">
</div>
```

with the CSS

```
.row {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.columns {
  padding: 0;
}

.featured-image img {
  height: 400px;
}

.featured-image-grid img {
  height: 200px;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image-grid > img {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
}
```

Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/magician11/pen/VaBmQb).

It needs some work to make it responsive, but it works for what I needed it to do.